# Sign in with next-auth from the server (same server)

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm using Next 13.5.4, next-auth 4.23.2 and the app folder structure.

I have the following route: "/api/validate" which will receive a POST request from another server. Inside this route I want to do a POST request to a next-auth Credentials route (inside /api/validate) and login that way.

However, when I fetch the CSRF token and do a POST request to the next-auth Credentials route, /api/auth/callback/validate, I get back the front-end code as a GET request instead of "authorize(credentials)" being called.

Here is /api/validate where I try to send a POST request to the NextJS Credentials route:

```
    let tokenTemp = await axios.get(
      process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL + "/api/auth/csrf"
    );
    
    const data = {
      csrfToken: tokenTemp.data.csrfToken,
      email: "gtest",
      password: "gtest",
      json: true,
      redirect: false,
    };

    let response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:5555/api/auth/callback/validate',
      data: data,
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
```

Here is the NextJS Credentials route:

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "validate",
      name: "validate",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "E-mail",
          type: "text",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials: any, request: any) {
        console.log("CRED: ");
        console.log("CRED: ", credentials, request);
        // console.log("CRED: ", request);
        let authToken = "";
        try {
          if (
            credentials.email === "gtest1" &&
            credentials.password === "gtest1"
          ) {
            return credentials;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return null;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    // signIn: "/api/auth/sigin",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The result I get is:
"<html... (and the rest of the HTML form)".

I was expecting the credentials to show up in the authorize(credentials, request) function and to be able to validate the credentials there, instead of getting a HTML page back.

Here is the code on GitHub:
https://github.com/jakobinn/nextauthcheck